# Mostrar alert dialog cuando se recibe una llamada

Tags: android, android-studio, diálogo

Estoy realizando una app que al recibir una llamada obtiene el número de la llamada entrante, lo busca en una BD, y muestra un mensaje con los datos asociados a ese numero. Hasta ahora la notificacon la doy con un Toast, quiero que se muestre algo como un alert dialog pero no funciona, como pordira hacer esto?....

con esta clase obtengo en numero de llamada entrante:

```
public class MyCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    String incomingNumber;


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //verfica que esta entrando una llamada y gruada el número...
        if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

            MiBaseDatos MDB = new MiBaseDatos(context);
            String numero = null;
            if (incomingNumber.charAt(0) == '+') {
                numero = incomingNumber.substring(3);
            }
            if (incomingNumber.charAt(0) == '9') {
                numero = incomingNumber.substring(4, 12);
            }
        Toast.makeText(context, "LLama de: " + MDB.recuperarPERSONA(numero).getName() + " " + incomingNumber, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


//            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
//
//                    builder.setTitle("LLamada Entrante de:")
//                    .setMessage(MDB.recuperarPERSONA(incomingNumber).getName() + " " + incomingNumber)
//                    .setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
//                    .show();


        } else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE) || intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "LLamada finalizada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }   

    }
```

Aquí muestro correctamente el mensaje con la clase tosat pero cuando la replazo por el alert dialg que esta comentariado no funciona....

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esto:

```
                String msj2="¿DESEA CONTINUAR?\n";
                AlertDialog.Builder dialogK2= new AlertDialog.Builder(micontexto);
                dialogK2.setTitle("ALERTA");
                dialogK2.setMessage(msj2);
                dialogK2.setCancelable(true);
                dialogK2.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null);
                dialogK2.setPositiveButton(R.string.accept, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //ejecuto mi codigo
                    }
                });
                dialogK2.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que en algunos sistemas operativos tendrás que ver la pantalla que muestra la llamada entrante, ya que este tiene una mayor prioridad.

**Algo importante para que el AlertDialog sea mostrado es asegurar que el contexto sea el de la `Activity`.**

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
        context);

// Configura el titulo.
alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("LLamada Entrante de:");

// Configura el mensaje.
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage(MDB.recuperarPERSONA(incomingNumber).getName() + " " + incomingNumber)
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                // Acción boton 
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
                // Cancela dialogo
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        }).create().show();
```

Comment: el problema es q la clase MyCallReceiver no esta asociada a ninguna actividad